# Calling a method vs assigning the return type

Tags: java

I would like to know which one is good. I am writing a for loop. In the condition part I am using str.length(). I wonder is this a good idea. I can also assign the value to an integer variable and use it in the loop.

Which one is the suitable/better way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**There is no distinct downside to calling a function in the loop condition expression** in the sense that "you really should never do it". *You want to watch out* when calling functions that have side effects, but even that can be acceptable in some circumstances.

There are three major reasons for moving function calls out of the loop (including the loop condition expressions):

- Performance. The function may (depending on the [JIT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) compiler) get called for every iteration of the loop, which costs you execution time. Particularly if the function's code has a higher order of complexity than O(1) *after the first execution*, this will increase the execution time. By how much depends entirely on exactly what the function in question does and how it is implemented.
- [Side effects](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Side_effect_%28computer_science%29). If the function has any side effects, those may (will) be executed repeatedly. This *might* be exactly what you want, but you need to be aware of it. A side effect is basically something that is observable outside of the function that is being called; for example, disk or network I/O are often considered to be side effects. A function that simply performs calculations on already available data is generally a [pure function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pure_function).
- Code clarity. Admittedly `str.length()` isn't very long, but if you have a complex calculation based around a function call in the loop conditional, code clarity can very easily suffer. For this reason it *may* be advantageous to move the loop termination condition calculation out of the loop condition expression itself. Beware of awakening the sleeping beast, however; make very sure that the refactored code actually *is* more readable.

For `str.length()` it doesn't really matter unless you are really after the last bit of performance you can get, particularly as [as has been pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19902830/486504) by [other answerers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19902752/486504), [String#length()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#length%28%29) is an O(1) complexity operation. Especially **in the general case,** if you need the additional performance, consider introducing a variable to hold the result of the function call and comparing against that rather than making the function call repeatedly.

**Personally,** I'd consider code clarity before worrying about micro-optimizations like exactly where to place a specific function call. But if you have everything else down and still need to ooze a little bit more performance out of the code, moving the function call out of the condition expression and using a local variable (preferably of a primitive type) is something worth considering. **Chances are, though,** that if you are worried about that, **you'll see bigger gains by considering a different algorithm.** (Do you *really* need to iterate over the string the way you are doing? Is there no other way to do what you are after?)

Comment: I see from your answer that performance depends on the type of compiler we are using. Does standard java compiler distributed by oracle does inlining the method call? Other thing is I did not understand the side effects part. Can you explain? Thank you

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanya I'm not really familiar with the specifics of the JITter, and what's more, that can change between releases. Other answers cover the specifics of `String#length()`; I'm answering your question more as asked in the title (in a general fashion) than focusing on the specific example you used. JIT inlining is effectively an implementation detail of the runtime environment: it's nice when it's there, but you can't rely on it being there in the general case.

Comment: @KrishnaChaitanya I added some explanation on side effects. Hopefully it's more clear now.

Answer (score 5):

If you use `str.length()` more than once or twice in the code, it's logical to extract it to a local var simply for brevity's sake. As for performance, it will most probably be exactly the same because the JIT compiler will inline that call, so the native code will be as if you have used a local variable.

Answer (score 3):

It usually doesn't matter. Use whichever makes your code clearer.

If a value is going to be used more than once, then there are two advantages to assigning it to a local variable:

- You can give the variable a **good name**, which makes your code easier to read an understand
- You can sometimes avoid a small amount of overhead by calling the method only once. This helps **performance** (although the difference is often too small to be noticeable - if in doubt you should benchmark)

Note: This advice only applies to pure functions. You need to be much more careful if the function has side effects, or might return a different value each time (like `Math.random()`) - in these cases you need to think much more carefully about the effect of multiple function calls.

Answer (score 2):

Calling `length` costs O(1) since the length is stored as a member - It's a constant operation, don't waste your time thinking about complexity and performance of this thing.

Comment: Actually I am planning to attend interviews. I am searching online for some interview questions. I saw few questions asking to search a subtring in a string which takes O(n) time or even less. So I just wanted to know which one is efficient.

Comment: This has nothing to do with writing `.length()` on the loop condition, since the length is stored as a field and getting it takes O(1), it won't affect time complexity.

Answer (score 1):

there are no difference at all between the two
But suppose if the str.length changes then in the for loop you need to manualy change the value

for example
String str="hi";
so in the for loop you write this way

```
for int i=0;i<str.length();i++)
{
}
```

or

```
for int i=0;i<2;i++)
    {
    }
```

Now suppose you want to change the str String str="hi1";

so in the for loop

```
for int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
    }
```

So I would suggest you to go for `str.length()`

Answer (score 0):

If you use `str.length` always this will evaluated. It is better to assign this value to variable and use that in for loop.

```
  for(int i=0; i<str.length;i++){ // str.length always evaluvated

  }

  int k=str.length; // only one time evaluvated

  for(int i=0;i<k;i++){

  }
```

If you are concern about performance you may use second approach.

Answer (score 0):

If  you are using `str.length()` in the code more than one time then you need to assign it to another variable and use it. Otherwise you can use `str.length()` itself.

**Reason for need**

When we call a method, each time the current position is stored in a DS (heap/stack) and go to the corresponding called method and make their operations 
And come back and from the DS retrieve the current position and do the normal operations.
That is actually happening. So when we do it so many times in a program it will cause the above mentioned scenario for several times.
 Therefore we need to create a local variable and assign into it and use where ever need in the program.

Comment: please explain why this is "needed". Seems like (premature) optimization